# how to delete file in folder and subfolder for space

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How to delete file from folder and subfolder currently using below command for delete logs but i want delete logs file in folder and subfolder in Linux .

currently i am doing enter every folder and delete log for specific year.
is there any command for delete same file from folder and subfolder in linux

volumes/abc/mbs2019-02-02.log
volumes/cdf/mbs2019-02-02.log

i want single command for delete both folder file in linux

```
sudo rm http.log2019*
```

Comment: You need to add a little more information, what's not working ?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q is about *using* a program and is more appropriate to https://superuser.com OR https://unix.stackexchange.com  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: It would be better to adjust the logging to compress logs or remove logs older than a certain amount of time.

Comment: Consider using logrotate utility for handling logs it come with many Linux distribution built-in.

Comment: Please @Addi Khan read Shellter's reccomendation and consider moving your question to for example superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure about what you're doing, use a command like this:

```
sudo rm -rf /myLogFolder/*
```

`-r` option will remove directories also without it `rm` will remove only files.

Note this will delete the content of the entire directory !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a file say `myFile.txt`, run:

```
sudo rm /path/to/directory/myFile.txt
```

**Note: If you are already in the working directory simply run, `sudo rm ./myFile.txt`**

If you want to delete a folder and everything it contains, run:

```
sudo rm -r /path/to/directory
```

**Note: The `-r` will trigger the deletion recursively.**

To delete say all your log files from a directory with a specific extension `.log` for your case am assuing, run:

```
sudo rm /path/to/directory/*.log
```

**Note: `*.log` can be anything `*.png`, `*.jpg`, etc.**

Hope this Helps!